# Mocking vert.x application with PowerMockito

Tags: mongodb, unit-testing, vert.x, powermockito

I'm trying to test my verticle but with mocked MongoDB (not to perform real DB actions during the process of unit testing), I've tried to mock my client, but looks like when I use `vertx.deployVerticle()` my mocks are not being taken into account.

Here's an example of my test setup:

```
@RunWith(VertxUnitRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({ MongoClient.class })
public class VerticleTest {
  @Rule
  public PowerMockRule rule = new PowerMockRule();
  private Vertx vertx;
  private Integer port;

  @Before
  public void setUp(TestContext context) throws Exception {
    vertx = Vertx.vertx();

    mockStatic(MongoClient.class);

    MongoClient mongo = Mockito.mock(MongoClientImpl.class);
    when(MongoClient.createShared(any(), any())).thenReturn(mongo);

    ServerSocket socket = new ServerSocket(0);
    port = socket.getLocalPort();
    socket.close();

    DeploymentOptions options = new DeploymentOptions().setConfig(new JsonObject().put("http.port", port));
    vertx.deployVerticle(TalWebVerticle.class.getName(), options, context.asyncAssertSuccess());
  }
```

And what I actually see, that is that `MongoClient.createShared` is still being called, though I've mocked it.
What can I do in this case?

**Edit 1.**
Looks like the problem is that `MongoClient` is an **interface** and **PowerMockito** is not able to mock static methods in this case.
I'm still trying to find workaround for this case.

Comment: You're right it because the `MongoClient` is an interface and feature that Interface could have static methods (or methods) has been added only in Java 8. And PowerMock still doesn't fully support Java 8. But I think, your issue could be easy fixed. The `MainMockTransformer` has check if a class which is being modified is interface and then skip modifying methods. I'm thinking about workaround for previous version and I'm going to fix it in next release.

Comment: Wow, great news, @ArthurZagretdinov. I will try `JMockIt` meanwhile, there are people saying that it might work. We'll see...

Comment: Cross-referencing.. also asked in Google Vertx group: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/vertx/iS6Yq_sflU4

Answer (score 2):

I didn't know that the `MongoClient` is an interface then I gave my first answer.

PowerMock doesn't supports mocking static calls interfaces (bug [#510](https://github.com/jayway/powermock/issues/510), Javaassist fixed exception, but mocking static methods still isn't supported). It will be called in next release.

I was focusing on issue in PowerMock, not why it's needed. I agree with answer which was provided in [Mailing List](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!search/TalWebVerticle.class/vertx/iS6Yq_sflU4/eq1rwv15BAAJ).

> You could work around it by creating a helper method in your own code
>   that returns MongoClient.createdShared(). Then in your test, mock that
>   helper to return your mocked MongoClientImp

But it will be not a work around, but right design solution. Mocking `MongoClient` is not a good approach, because [you should not mock types you don't own](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/wiki/How-to-write-good-tests#dont-mock-type-you-dont-own).

So better way will be create a custom helper which will create `MongoClient`for you and then mock this the helper in unit test. Also you will need integration tests for this helper which will call real `MongoClient.createdShared()`.

If you don't have an opportunity to change code (or you don't want to change code without tests), then I've create an [example](https://github.com/thekingnothing/stackoverflow/tree/master/q36129716) with work around how PowerMock bug could be bypassed.

Main ideas:

- create a custom `MainMockTransformer`. The transformer will transform interfaces classes to enable supporting mock static calls for interfaces
- create a custom `PowerMockRunner` which will be used to add the custom `MockTransformer` to transformers chains.

Please, bring to notice on packages name where these new classes are located. It's important. If you want to move them into another packages then you will need to add these new packages to `@PowerMockIgnore`.

Comment: Sorry for this confusion, it's just a bit broken code in my first code.
I've removed it accidentally, when removing unnecessary parts. Even with `mockStatic(MongoClient.class)` it fails. Thank you, I will update my initial post.

Comment: I've changed answer.